# Postgres: store login settings for multiple databases for quick login?

Tags: aws, postgresql, configure

I have multiple databases that I am logging into on AWS and right now I am entering the full url for the database i.e.,

```
psql -d psql -d postgresql://user:pass@host:port/dbname more stuff
```

I would like to do something link [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/115838/what-is-the-right-file-permission-for-a-pem-file-to-ssh-and-scp?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa&newreg=d0fd9b25e98d4b90913b3f140e889d91).

Where I have some kind of config file like from the example I linked,

```
Name my_database1
    Hostname=host_to_database
    Port=port_to_database
    User=username
    Pass=password
    DBName=dbname
Name my_database2
    Hostname=host_to_database2
    Port=port_to_database2
    User=username2
    Pass=password2
    DBName=dbname2
```

Then I would just have to run `psql -d my_database1`
How do I do that?

Comment: Set some variables? `psql -d $my_database1`

Answer (score 1):

It is unlikely you would be able to get to a point where you literally were able to type `psql -d my_database1`, however you could use shell variables (as suggested in @Patrick's comment) or aliases to accomplish remembering/typing less.

I tend to use [linux aliases](http://www.linfo.org/alias.html), but straight from that alias page (emphasis my own):

> The alias command is built into a number of shells including ash, bash (the default shell on most Linux systems), csh and ksh. It is one of several ways to customize the shell (another is **setting environmental variables**).

For example, you could create a `~/.profile` (or append to it) with something along these lines:

```
alias psql_my_database1="psql -d postgresql://user:pass@host:port/dbname more stuff"
alias psql_my_database2="psql -d postgresql://user:pass@host:port/otherdbname"
```